# Bookmark window.location javascript

Tags: javascript, php

The code below is a bookmark that opens the page im on and inserts it into a php query.

How can I make the code below insert only the "domain.com" of the page im on

Not the "https://www." part

javascript:var loadWho=window.open('http:/'+'/www.example.com/test.php?domain=**'+window.location.href.replace('#','|'));**

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location.hostname`:

```
var domain=window.location.hostname.replace("www.","")
```